# How can I filter by an array which is contained as a value of a struct

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, multidimensional-array

Below is the data structure which I'm storing in an array called **arrayEV**
I'm pretty sure I can filter by the eventname in the top array. 
However I'm not sure how to filter the arrays by things in the subarray [heatlane] so I only want the main arrayEV to show up when a condition is met by something in the [heatlane]

```
struct events {
    var eventnumber:Int
    var eventname:String
    var swimmers:[heatlane]?
}

struct heatlane{
    var heat:Int
    var lane:Int
    var age:Int
    var swimmer:String
    var team:String
    var seedTime:String
    var finalsTime:String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference in approach in filtering by simple property (like `Int`) or more complex one (like `Array` or others). You should just pass condition by which elements should be filtered.

If you would like to filter events and have only these which event's name starts with "A" you'd write:

```
let prefixedWithA = events.filter{ $0.eventname.hasPrefix("A") }
```

If you would like to filter events that have swimmer whose name is prefixed with "A" you'd write:

```
let hasSwimmerPrefixedWithA = events.filter{ $0.swimmers?.contains(where: {$0.swimmer.hasPrefix("A")}) ?? false }
```

Comment: thanks for this...working on implementaiton now with a search bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.filter` ..

```
var array: [Any] = []
var heatlaneArr: [heatlane] = []
array.append(heatlaneArr)
```

Filter array like this, check out every array element of array

```
let findHeatlaneArray = array.filter { (obj) -> Bool in
   return ((obj as? [heatlane]) != nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let resultFilter = arrayEV.filter { (events) -> Bool in
        guard let swimmers = events.swimmers else { return false } // check  swimmers not nil
        let result = swimmers.filter({ $0.age == 1}) // age condition
        return result.count ==  0 ? false : true
    }
```